# Neural Network Neurons output numbers approach 1

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

Calculate the displacement parameters and weights of the neuron with input x = [1,2] to approach the output value 1 (The neural circuit should also be shown)

Comment: There's no question here, this looks more like an assignment.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.